# multiple images with figure tag with 45% width each images

Tags: css

I want add 5 images using figure and figcaption tag. I want show 2 images on page using width 45%. I am doing for 2 days but 2nd image not floating left.

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container img {
  width: 45%;
}

figcaption {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  display: inline;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: “”;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <figure class="imgcol">
    <figcaption> Experimentation with color and texture. </figcaption>
    <img src="" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />

    <figcaption> Playing with blending mode in photoshop. </figcaption>
    <img src="" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />

    <figcaption> Trying to create 80's style glow. </figcaption>
    <img src="" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />

    <figcaption> Drips created using Photoshop brushes </figcaption>
    <img src="" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />

    <figcaption> Creating shapes using repetition. </figcaption>
    <img src="" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 figure {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width:45%;
 }

 .container img {
    max-width:100%;
}

figcaption {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: “”;
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
    <figure class="imgcol"> 
        <figcaption> Experimentation with color and texture. </figcaption> 
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Yvihcj.gif" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
    </figure>
         
    <figure class="imgcol"> 
         <figcaption> Playing with blending mode in photoshop. </figcaption>
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Yvihcj.gif" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
    </figure>
         
    <figure class="imgcol"> 
         <figcaption> Trying to create 80's style glow. </figcaption>
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Yvihcj.gif" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
    </figure>
         
    <figure class="imgcol"> 
         <figcaption> Drips created using Photoshop brushes </figcaption> 
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Yvihcj.gif" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
    </figure>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can i use 1 figure tag  for 5 images.

Comment: but i want add figcaption on web also

Comment: why not all the image size 45%. Images are displaying on different sizes.

Comment: Means "figcaption will come top of every images"

Comment: updated answer above, now images will be of same width, but might not be same height